# 90 degrees CCW permutation of a square ($D_4$)

Tags: permutations

Given a square and a permutation of 90 degrees counter-clockwise, what is the order of this finite symmetry group?
Here's an attempt:
$$\rho =\begin{bmatrix}
1 &2  &3  &4 \\ 
\rho (1) &\rho(2)  &\rho(3)  &\rho(4) 
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 &2  &3  &4 \\ 
 2&3  &4  &1 
\end{bmatrix}$$

I want to find the order of this symmetry group.

This is a group of $S_{4}$.
I'm tempted to say the order of $S_{n}$ is $4$ but this doesn't look right given the constraint of a 90 degrees counter-clockwise permutation. 
That means, if we have the square with sides labelled 1,2,3 and 4 as reflected in the matrix above, only the below are permitted
$$1\rightarrow 2 \\
2\rightarrow 3\\
3\rightarrow 4\\
4\rightarrow 1.$$

Have I gone wrong anywhere? 
Also, the square is a $D_{4}$, how do I determine $D_{4}\leq S_{n}$?

Suppose, the reflection is $\phi$:

$$\phi =\begin{bmatrix}
1 &2  &3  &4 \\ 
 2&1  &4  &3 
\end{bmatrix}$$
(notation implies subgroup)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! I am not following your question $100\%$: am I right that your goal is to derive the order of the symmetry group of the square with corners $1,2,3,4$ starting from the assumption that it has to be a subgroup of $S_4$? Note that $S_4$ has order $4!$.

Comment: There was a typing error. 4! was what I had in mind but I'm couldn't convinced myself geometrically. 
It is a subgroup of 4. That is a given.
ignoring the reflection for the moment, with permutation of 90 degrees CCW alone, there is no way 1 could be mapped to 4 in a single 'move'.

Comment: When you write "_this_ finite symmetry group" (emphasis added), do you mean the group generated by the rotation $\rho$, the group of all symmetries of the square, or something else? (Note that the set $\{\rho\}$ is not closed under composition, nor is the set $\{e, rho\}$ consisting of $\rho$ and the identity map.)

Comment: I do not know. It was a question copied from the blackboard during lesson :(

Comment: @user86418 why is it not closed under composition?

Comment: @opensource.11: If you rotate a square through a quarter turn and then through a quarter turn again, the overall result is not a rotation through a quarter turn. Briefly, "$\{\rho\}$ is not closed under composition". :) (My guess is "this group" refers to "the group _generated by_ the rotation $\rho$", a.k.a., the smallest group of symmetries of the square that contains a quarter-turn, but it's best to clarify with your instructor.) Incidentally, it's also a good idea to make a square from paper and to number its vertices. Then you can experiment by physically manipulating a piece of paper.